# Is it possible to use mod_rewrite htaccess to rewrite a url from name to id.

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If I have a URL`http://www.domain.com/listing.php?company_id=1`  is it possible for me to re-write that to `http://www.domain.com/company-name` by using that id to pull the name from the database.

Or do I have to change listing.php to make it `?company_name=company-name`

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: rewrite will just help you to write your URL in a cool way, but it's just a regexp parser as far as I know... maybe you could solve it with HTML5 history and Ajax

Comment: Check out the map function. I know map text files (which I export from a database), but I believe mod_rewrite also does map from a database. There are probably questions here covering this, but if this is still hanging tomorrow, I'll try to do an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map function allows using no id in the url at all, while still using the id in the rewritten url to do the database lookup.

```
http://www.domain.com/another-one
```

maps to

```
http://www.domain.com/listing.php?company_id=3423
```

Here is how I use map text files, which I generate from a database query. I believe mod_rewrite also does mapping to a database directly, of which I'm unfamiliar (maybe someone can provide that answer). I use Helicon Tech's isapi_rewrite v3, which works like mod_rewrite, so this should work for you.

Sample map file named map_company.txt

```
some-company 12
another-one 3423
freds-fill-dirt-and-croissants 44
```

The rewrite rules:

```
RewriteMap map_company txt:map_company.txt [NC] 

RewriteCond ${map_company:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /listing.php?company_id=${map_company:$1} [NC,QSA,L]
```

RewriteMap assigns the map_company.txt text file to a variable named map_company (named the same just to be consistent).

RewriteRule is doing the work. It captures everything after the slash into `$1`, then rewrites it to your listing.php url. The `${map_company:$1}` is looking up the url in the map file, and returning the id.

RewriteCond is just doing a double-check to see if the listing is there. The $1 is coming from the RewriteRule url, the NOT_FOUND is a default value if not found, and the condition is if it's not-NOT_FOUND (a little tangled - but it's just checking if it's in the file). If it's in the file, the RewriteRule will be run. If it's not in the file, it skips the RewriteRule, and falls through to more rules (perhaps to a page-not-found or some other default).

Comment: Thanks so much.  I learned a lot.  I had no idea about ReweriteMap.  Right now I get an "Internal Server Error" so not sure if it's an issue with my host or the code, but I'm on Live Chat right now with HostGator so hopefully we can get it figured out!

Comment: Apparently my host doesn't support it! :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer checkmark. Make sure the location of the file is ok - mine are at the website root, with my .htaccess file, so the simple filename-only works. I think you can do the full C:\... path too, but hosts often don't like that either. Worst case, M_rk's answer with Devraj's comments is a decent solution too; it just has an id in it.

Comment: So I can use PHP to get the values from the database in that .txt file?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but generally yes, you could write some code that reads the database and creates the .txt file.

Comment: Ohh ok I gotcha, so you do all the PHP in a .php file and then create the txt file and pass some variables.

Comment: When it's done, you want to end up with a text file that simply looks like the sample lines above. You could even hand create it if your data doesn't change all that often. If you need more on this, try looking for questions about exporting data with PHP (out of my realm, sorry). All this still depends on your host supporting it though - or you'll need to do something like M_rk's answer instead.

Comment: Yeah for now I can't do anything but I think we are going to upgrade to a VPS server which does support it.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I know this's old, but with `RewriteMap`, using DBM format is much faster. See [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the id in both the urls, but only use the full name in the pretty link for the user. 
The following would rewrite `http://www.domain.com/42/company_name` to `http://www.domain.com/listing.php?company_id=42` and just discard the company name.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/$ /listing.php?company_id=$1 [L]
```

Note that a user could also visit `http://www.domain.com/42/wrong_name` and still land on the right page with the right company name. If this isn't desired you could change the rule to `/listing.php?company_id=$1&company_name=$2` and check for equality in `listings.php`

Comment: If the `company-name` slug was guaranteed to be unique, they could use that instead of the ID.

Comment: @Phil Even if it was unique I wouldn't recommend using it since using the `id` would result in a faster lookup in the database.

Comment: CMSes solve this problem by "creating" a lower case url representation of the title, and substituting the space with underscores. This process would check if the generated alias is unique when storing the record. Obviously to ensure its unique. You can then index this property for performance.

Comment: @Devraj Yes, the lower-case-hyphens or underscores is a good url, for SEO as well as being clean/unique. Then, if it's not a match to the correct string, the SEO world recommends a 301 redirect to the correct value. This helps prevent "random" urls of your website getting indexed by search engines.

Comment: Another tweak would be to put the company name first, as `http://www.domain.com/company-name/42`. Search engines may give more weight to the earlier part of the url (subject to all we really can do is guess about SEO). `RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([\d]+)$ /listing.php?company_id=$1 [L]` Tweaking the rule to just look for not-slash, then slash (instead of explicit characters), then capture the digits.